# "a great deal" vs. "considerably"

Tags: word-choice

There is a task from a textbook to choose the correct alternative in this sentence:

> Does **a great deal**/**considerably** wider accessibility inevitably mean a decline in the quest for serious reflection and deeper understanding?"

I know that the correct answer is **considerably**, but I have no idea what's wrong with **a great deal**. And not even sure it actually is wrong.

Attached grammar gives the following information:

> We can use the following words to intensify and modify comparatives:
>
> **considerably**/far/much/a lot/**a great deal** more/less interesting than

I've checked internet, different dictionaries and grammars, but still don't know why **a great deal** is inappropriate in this case. I've also asked few native speakers and they confirmed that **a great deal** actually seems to be inappropriate.

So could anyone, please, explain to me why **considerably** is better in this case?

Comment: Is "considerably" more official than "a great deal" ? It looks more official to me

Comment: I bet it's collocation: [considerably + wider](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22considerably+wider%22) VS [great deal + wider](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22great+deal+wider%22&tbm=bks) The former is more popular. As to "why", no idea, but *considerably* is perhaps a touch more formal. Is this exercise aimed at  CAE/Advanced/IELTS 8?

Comment: [great deal + taller](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22great+deal+taller%22)  2,160 results on Google Books compared to 14,800 results for [considerably +  taller](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22considerably+taller%22) This might help explain why "considerably" is considered the *correct* answer, but I'd say it's fairer to say it is the "more appropriate" answer.

Comment: The problem is the construction of this particular sentence, which uses a comparative adjective as opposed to the comparative structure 'more/less _____ than" that you found in your research.  Something can BE a great deal wider, but your question would need to be worded, 'Does HAVING a great deal wider accessibility inevitably mean...?' or 'Is a great deal wider accessibility _______?'

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, it's a textbook for CAE. It might depend on region, but "a great deal" is actually formal.

Comment: @Egox Could you, please, expand a little more on your explanation? I don't quite understand it

Comment: That's why I said "Perhaps" *considerably* is a touch (slightly) more formal. Both forms are formal, and I don't see why adding "having", suggested by Egox, makes any significant difference. You could add *having* to both phrases. Tricky question, and plenty of food for thought here.

Comment: @Choksy: For example, the indicitive 'John is a great deal (considerably) taller (than Mike)' can be made interrogative:  'Is John a great deal taller (than Mike)?'  Now use your verb, 'mean', in similar statements:  John **being** a great deal taller means that....' or the interrogation 'Does John **being** a great deal taller mean that...?'  Another option would be 'Is the fact that John is a great deal taller indicative of...?'

Comment: @Egox And what does it have to do with the choice of words in question?

Comment: @Choksy:  I suspect that the confusion comes from questions regarding the meaning of words.  For example, 'Does "a great deal taller" mean the same thing as "considerably taller"?  This question can be confused with the one that you have cited, but it is clearly (if properly punctuated) a different sense of the verb 'mean'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA:  I see your point.  On further thought, the problem could be that 'consider' has the capacity to compare (and can thus imply comparison without the need to state as much) whereas 'a great deal' lacks this capacity (and thus we have to spell it out).

Comment: The main aims of these Advanced level text books is to increase native sounding speech, idioms, slang etc. you are more likely to meet up with phrasal verbs and idioms at this level than at Elementary. The sentence: *A is considerably more difficult than B* (413,000 hits on Google Books)  and  *A is a great deal more diffcult than B* ( 35,200 hits) mean the same,  the only difference being is that the  former is considerably more common. :) But I suspect it must have something to do with the auxiliary verb: *Does a great deal wider accessibility...* Looks more convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (*CGEL*), "attributive AdjPs [adjective phrases]" do not permit "prehead NP [noun phrase] modifiers". (See chapter 6, § 3.3, pages 551–2.)

*Attributive* refers to the common use of adjective phrases inside a noun phrase, preceding the noun that they modify. For example, in "a very short book", *very short* is an attributive adjective phrase. (Attributive is mostly as opposed to *predicative* — for example, "the book is *very short*" contains a predicative adjective phrase — though there also exist some less-common functions that are neither attributive nor predicative, such as in "*as short* a book as that" and "I want to read something *short*".)

A "prehead noun phrase modifier" is a noun phrase that precedes and modifies (in this case) an adjective. So in "a great deal wider", *a great deal* is a prehead noun phrase modifier (modifying *wider*).

So the problem in your example is that since "a great deal wider" contains a prehead noun phrase modifier, it can't be used in attributive position; *"a great deal wider accessibility" is not grammatical.

(In addition to an example with "a great deal better", *CGEL* also gives an example with "three years old": we can say "a three-year-old child", and "the child is three years old", but not *"a three years old child". It also gives a *counterexample* with "(a) lot": "She's a lot better player than me", meaning "She's a player who's a lot better than me." Though personally I find this counterexample pretty questionable; *I* would never say it that way, anyway.)

I don't know if that really answers your question "why", but at least it should help you understand the rule so you can apply it in the future. I hope that's almost as satisfying. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to make sure that I understood you rightly. 
"This is a great deal better book" - is wrong, instead I should say "This is a considerably better book".
But both "This book is a great deal better" and "This book is considerably better" are correct. Am I right?

Comment: @Chosky: Yes, exactly.